# How I can extract text from a incoming webhook field?

Tags: discord.js

Is possible to extract a variant code from any incoming webhook and make bot send a new message with only that variant code?

Webhook example:
[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you mean is: *How can I extract text **from an embed sent by a webhook**?*
Webhooks often send embeds, just because is a prettier way of sending data. The thing you see when you send a YouTube or Twitter link is also an embed.

If this is the case, I'll assume that the embed you're referring to is the first and only embed of the message. I'll also assume that `message` is the message sent by the webhook.

```js
let embed = message.embeds[0], // This is the embed we're searching in.
  field, text, number;
if (!embed) return; // If there are no embeds in the message, return.

for (let f of embed.fields) { // Loop through every field in the embed...
  if (f.name == 'Sizes') { // ...until you find the one named 'Sizes'
    field = f; // Then store it into the field variable
    break; // Exit the loop
  }
}
if (!field) return; // If there are no 'Sizes' fields, return.

// This will split the message in two parts to get the 2nd
// It will get the string cantaining the number
text = field.value.split('-')[1].trim();

// If you want the result as a number, you can parse it:
number = parseInt(text);
```

Comment: thanks you so much for help, one question, if I want the bot to do this as soon as I get a new message, I need to insert in the code `client.on('message', (receivedMessage) => {`, but when i do that, the bot returns _message is not defined_. thanks again for your response

Comment: It throws "message is not defined" because in your `'message'` event handler you declared the message parameter as `receivedMessage`: if you change that to `message` (or if you change `message` in `receivedMessage`) it should work. (PS: I am in fact Italian, but let's keep the conversation in English so that everybody can understand it ;))

Comment: Hi, But If there are more rows in the "sizes" field what happens?

Comment: It will get everything after the first `-`. What would want it to do?